# Constructing variables within a for loop

Tags: python, oop, for-loop, instance

Let's say I want to create a lot of instances of a class but don't want to write the variable name down for every instance.

What I want:

```py
value1 = class(value1)
value2 = class(value2)
.
.
.
```

My idea was:

```py
list = ['One','Two','Three']

for value in list:
    value = class(value)
```

The result is not what I wanted. Python creates the variable 'value' and overrides it with the values of the list.

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but I'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`, in this case, a `list` seems appropriate

Comment: `values = [class(x) for x in list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that you should not use `list` as a variable name, as it is reserved as a keyword by Python itself. Then, you could have another list, `instanceList` lets say, in which you will append every newly created instance of a class:

```
myList = ['One','Two','Three']
instanceList = []

for value in myList:
    instanceList.append(class(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to build a list of class instances from a list of values:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

values = ['One','Two','Three']
instances = [A(v) for v in values]
```

```py
>>> print(list(o.value for o in instances))
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Comment: `[A(v) for v in values]` is a list comprehension - he just uses a generator expression to print the results.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question/remark, but if you need a generator instead of a list, then you can just replace `instances = [...]` by `instances = (...)`. Another legitimate option is to use a for-loop as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55286849/1720199).